# Split string into multiple Textboxes in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, regex, string, windows-phone-8, split

Since there's the `2048x2048 pixel` limit for UIElements in WPhone, I'm trying to split a string that is too long to be shown.

I've tried implementing the `ScrollableTextBlock`done [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) but to no success. So I'm struggling to do it in another way.

I've tried using a wildcard in the text, specifically `\r\n`: when it's reached, a method `Splitter` done with `Regex` returns the remaining substring:

```
private string Splitter(string str1)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str1,"\r\n");
        int count = matches.Count / 2; //i want to split every text in half avoiding word truncating, 
        //so I'm getting the NewLine closest to the middle of the text
        int pos= matches[count].Index; //I get the index of the char in str1
        return str1.Substring(pos); 
    }
```

But it gives me the ArgumentIsNullException when reaching `matches[count]`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using regex? Why not just `str1.Split("\r\n")`? Unfortunately, your problem description is not very clear. You should provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and you should provide the _complete_ exception information (message, stack trace, and clear, unambiguous description of the program statement where it happens).

Comment: Actually, the code works correctly. With the input string `1 line\r\n1 line\r\n3 line\r\n4 line\r\n5 line\r\n6 line`, the result is `\n4 line\r\n5 line\r\n6 line`. Perhaps, you should check if `str1` is not empty or null in the first place, then if matches are found at all.

Comment: @stribizhev that's right, sorry @Peter Duniho for not explaining myself correctly. Anyway, I ended up using @Rufus L solution, and the strange thing is that the wildcard `\r\n` isn't found at all on the string text, which is very strange. Is there a particulat format for the searched string in `Regex.Matches`?

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi: Please check my answer. BTW, you can now upvote, congratulations! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need some validation on your argument and on `matches.Count`:

```
private static string Splitter(string str1)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1)) return str1;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str1, "\r\n");

    if (matches.Count == 0) return str1;

    int count = matches.Count / 2;
    int pos = matches[count].Index;
    return str1.Substring(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one potential problem with Rufus' code is that there might be different newline symbols or sequences. I have seen files with `\r\n` and `\n` in them. Thus, I'd rather use a regex that will capture the most probable occurrences - `[\r\n]+`. I suspect the input file you have also contains just `\n` new line separator.

```
private static string Splitter(string str1)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1)) return str1;
    var matches = Regex.Matches(str1, @"[\r\n]+");

    if (matches.Count == 0)
       return str1;
    else
    {
       var count = matches.Count / 2;
       var pos = matches[count].Index;
       return str1.Substring(pos);
    }
}

// Input: "111\n2222\n3333"
// Output: "\n3333"
```

Comment: @RufusL: Thank you for letting know, I decided to edit my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. I ended up using the `.Split` method because the `Regex` didn't always found `\r\n` in my string, which is strange (strings are loaded from an SQLite database, maybe it has something to do with the UTF-8 coding?) Anyway, the new `Splitter` method is maybe inefficent and raw, but works: it splits text into two TextBlocks. I'm posting it anyway, maybe someone can use it too.

```
private void Splitter(string str)
    {

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(); //it's more efficent for appending strings in a loop
        string [] words = str.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        int length=words.Length;
        int half = length / 2;

        //Appending first half
        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++)
        {
            build.Append(words[i]+"\r\n"); //reintroducing the \r\n because I need 
                                    //to put a System.Enviornment.NewLine in place
                                    //(and the Split method eliminates it)
        }
        txtTextBlock1.Text = build.ToString();
        build.Clear();
        //Appending second half
        for (int i = half; i < length; i++)
        {
            build.Append(words[i] + "\r\n");
        }
        txtTextBlock2.Text = build.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks a lot to everyone for the help.